# Why won't Bootstrap columns work in this small HTML/CSS snippet?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I expect to have a left column 2 units wide and a right area 10 units long. However, for some strange reason it is not coming out that way.

Anyone know why not?

```css
#left {
  background-color: green;
}
#right {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="main-row" class="row">
  <div id="left" class="col-xs-2">
    <p>Yo</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">A Button</button>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="col-xs-10">
    Ho
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using Bootstrap 3 HTML with Bootstrap 2 CSS.

Change your link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```